# InertiaJS Request updated data from server while preserving state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

In my Vue app, I have a set of filters that build a query string upon selection and append it to the url. I want to have the filters applied and the data to be refreshed while also preserving state so that the user can keep adding filters without the modal being closed. I thought the `only` property would achieve this but it does not, the page still loses state. Here is what I've tested so far:

1. This achieves what I want (modal is not closed) but the data is not updated.

   `this.$inertia.visit(url, { preserveState: true })`
2. This updates the data correctly, but still loses state as if the `preserveState` property is overidden (modal is closed)

   ```
   ...
   props: ['data'],
   ...

   this.$inertia.visit(url, { 
       preserverState: true, 
       only: ['data'] 
   })
   ```

Is this possible with another method of hitting the url or custom option?

Answer (score 2):

After some messing with configuration options, I found a way to update data while preserving state. Simply use the `onSuccess` option while preserving state:

```
...
props: ['data'],
...

this.$inertia.visit(url, {
    preserveState: true,
    onSuccess: page => {
        this.data = page.props.data;
    }
})
```